# Proper use of “repertoire”

Tags: word-choice, american-english

Could the word *repertoire* be used to describe one’s behavior as a façade?

Comment: What really do you understand by *repertoire*, and in what way could it be related to "one's behavior as a facade" (whatever that is)? Need more details.

Comment: Please tell us what you found in the dictionary and which meaning you think can be used as a facade. If you have questions about how we can help you, please visit the [help](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) center.

Answer (score 1):

No. The word repertoire describes a set of skills or knowledge that one has at their disposal and makes frequent use of. One might have a repertoire of deceptions and disingenuous behaviors that they use to put forth a facade, but the repertoire is not the behavior or the facade; it is the catalog of skills and knowledge being drawn on.

Answer (score 0):

I don't find it very satisfying, but here are some attempts:

> She had a very carefully designed repertoire that projected her desired  persona.
>
> She never did or said anything that was not a part of her carefully crafted repertoire.